# <p> alignment with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can I push  `<p>Copyright &copy;<a href="#"></a></p>`this html element with bootstrap without using div tag.
I tryed to use push_2 and pull_2 but seems not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "offset", not push.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ky7qk/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <p class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6"></p>
</div>

p {
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```